# The listview not displaying correctly as the graphical layout shows

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an issue with my listview it is supposed to have a button at the top and under is the listview.

However, as I run my application the listview completely covers the button. What would be the main cause of this problem?

edit - sorry for the large images, i'm not sure how to resize them

[image]

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/buttonShow" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listDays"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/buttonList"/>

</RelativeLayout>


public class SimpleListView extends ListActivity{

    String[] days;
    Button mButtonList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mButtonList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
        //mButtonList.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        days = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.daysArray);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, days));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this Simply:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried this one and looked like it would work however, the issue still persists. I will add the java code as there may be a problem in there?

Comment: I had to comment that out since, using it crashed the activity. "activity has stopped" error message.

Comment: it crashed because you are finding out your button id before it.. So change it and set after setContentView method..

Comment: That made so much sense, but it's still crashing??

Comment: I'm working with the code and the setContentView is not working well with the extends ListActivity, with just extends Activity the button shows up but I had to comment out the listview code to check that.

Comment: The problem has been solved, thanks for your help. I did multiple things so i'm not sure the root cause but I did change in the layout "android:id="@+id/android:list".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide code if you want us to be able to fix it.  Please provide your xml layout.  However, without further information, it is probably that you just have an issue with your xml layout.  Here is a layout that will probably work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/header_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_button"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've edited in the code from xml and class, the xml is very similar and initially used linearlayout. But changing to relative also unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You xml code looks about right

are you setting the property visibility.gone anywhere in the code?

Comment: nope, definitely do not have that anywhere. Seems very weird.